# How to get everything from a mysql database when not knowing table and column names?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database on an external domain. Phpmyadmin is not installed on the server. I do neither know the table names nor do I know the column names. Is there a way to somehow create a view in PHP that shows me everything that is in the db with all the column and table names?

Answer (score 6):

You can query the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/columns-table.html) table:

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
```

Comment: Yours and the answer below dont give me any results. I know that I only have reading access to the database. Could there be a problem? Shouldn´t be, should it?

Comment: You might not have read access to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables.  I wouldn't give anyone read access to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables if I were the database administrator.

Answer (score 0):

on mysql command you can use `show databases` and `show tables`

or on php script you can `use mysql_list_dbs()` and `mysql_list_tables()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-dbs.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

Answer (score 0):

This script uses the PDO to execute the queries which return the database tables and tables columns. It uses a simple layout that you can personalize.

```
<?php

    $host = '';
    $dbname = '';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF-8", $username, $password);

    $sth = $db->prepare("SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM $dbname");
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $info) {
        echo "<p><b>".$info['Name']."</b><br />";

        $sth2 = $db->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $dbname.{$info['Name']};");
        $sth2->execute();
        $result2 = $sth2->fetchAll();
        foreach ($result2 as $info2)
            echo " - ".$info2['Field']."<br />";

        echo "</p>";
    }

?>
```